# How to transfer the colors of an image to another?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

How do I get the image color tones of an image and set it to another one?

I have these two images and want to make Ashley Benson in Mona Lisa's image colors.

[image]
[image]

Comment: "style transfer" requires AI. -- please take the [tour] and review [ask]. you are responsible for researching your own question.

Comment: The Mona Lisa doesn’t have a filter, it is a painting made by a person, who interpreted what he saw. If it is just transferring the color scheme, that can be done quite simply. Reinterpreting a photograph to make it similar to another is hugely complex, and requires Deep Learning as already suggested. But neither of these things are “filters”.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Of course, I know that. I want to use the same color tones as in the picture.

Comment: So you want to transfer the color scheme,  not the filter. It helps if you use the right names… :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think this is in reference to histogram matching

Comment: @JeruLuke That is indeed what I was thinking, though I have actually never done it with color histograms. Should be possible though!

Comment: @CrisLuengo if done across 3 channels separately followed by merging, it would be color histogram

Comment: @JeruLuke You do get some false colors that way: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYzvC.jpg But both images being nearly monochromatic helps!

Comment: @CrisLuengo This is weird. My suggestion was based on this blog post: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/02/08/histogram-matching-with-opencv-scikit-image-and-python/&ved=2ahUKEwiImeaEjpn4AhUm4TgGHTaiDrkQFnoECAYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3BOQEqsW1StEni0APXGRLV

Comment: @CrisLuengo please let me to know how did you train the model. I ran `python neural_style/neural_style.py train --dataset ./images --style-image ./images/style-images/mosaic.jpg --save-model-dir ./saved_models --epochs 2 --cuda 0` but it built some `***.model` file but I need a `***.pth` file.

Comment: @JeruLuke `skimage.exposure.match_histograms` indeed process each channel independently. I guess that works if the histograms are more similar? I think the problem here is the large white area of the background, the first image doesn't have uniform areas like that.

Comment: @JohnGoodman I didn't train a model, I just applied histogram matching like I was discussing with Jeru.

Comment: See https://pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/

Comment: @fmw42 That works surprisingly well! I've used that trick only on the a,b channels, not L, because that made the picture very dark. https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2SRg.jpg

Comment: @Cris Luengo.  I had not thought about doing it in LAB colorspace.  I will have to investigate that further for my own benefit. Thanks.

Comment: @Cris Luengo. I implemented your LAB method using just the A,B channels and that does work quite well on this image pair. Indeed, much better than using all 3 channels. My result looks just like what you posted in your link. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there could be a "filter" to do it.

Using classical computer vision you could make Fast Fourier Transform of each image, and than replace low-frequency components of Ashley Benson image with Mona Lisa's. But in this case you can only change the color domain of the image. Code example here:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

lisa = cv2.imread(r"path/to/monalisa")
ashley = cv2.imread(r"path/to/ashley")

def domain_adoptation(src, trg, freq):

    """
    Parameters: 
    src - source image, which style has to be changed
    trg - target image, which low-frequency domain will be adopted
    freq - number of frequencies to be used

    Returns:
    result - np.array based on srs image (shape and high frequencies) 
         with low frequencies of the target image
    """

    result = np.zeros((src.shape[0],src.shape[1],src.shape[2]))

    for i in range(src.shape[2]):
        trg_fft = np.fft.fft2(trg[:,:,i])
        src_fft = np.fft.fft2(src[:,:,i])

        trg_fft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(trg_fft)
        src_fft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(src_fft)

        src_fft_shift[src.shape[0]//2-freq:src.shape[0]//2+freq,
                         src.shape[1]//2-freq:src.shape[1]//2+freq] = \
            trg_fft_shift[trg.shape[0]//2-freq:trg.shape[0]//2+freq,
                           trg.shape[1]//2-freq:trg.shape[1]//2+freq]

        src_ifft_shift = np.fft.ifftshift(src_fft_shift)

        result[:,:,i] = np.fft.ifft2(src_ifft_shift)
        result[:,:,i] = np.abs(result[:,:,i])

    result = np.float32(result)
    result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    result = cv2.normalize(result,None,0,1,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

    return result

image = domain_adoptation(src=ashley,trg=lisa,freq=1)
plt.imshow(a)
```

And there's a GIF:

[image: Ashley to Lisa]

If you want to have better results, you can take a look at the quite old deep learning method called "[Fast neural style](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/main/fast_neural_style)". To do this with Mona Lisa's image, you need to train your own model using the examples above. You can check pretrained models in [this colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vfkA5EtnyFVR_EmoJ-UT62bUQoy8Si8a?usp=sharing). Trained models (for each style its own model) give these results:

[image: candy]
[image: mosaic]

Of course there are many modern state-of-the-art approaches of style transfer, see [here](https://paperswithcode.com/task/style-transfer).

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. Could you also show an example to get a result like fast neural style with given images.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot see changes

Comment: Thank you Maxim, I meant how did you get that result? What combination of commands have you used? Thank you again.

Comment: When you see the power of those DL filters, there is no doubt they could as well transfer the original style.

Comment: @JohnGoodman added link to Colab

Comment: Thank you Maxim for the answer. The fast neural style was useful.